# tabs to be displayed vertically and horizontally

Tags: html, dojo

can we create dojo tabs horizontally and vertically at a time. I tried the below code but it is displaying only second div showing tabs horizontally. With respect to that i want to show tabs at the top so that user can select any required tab shown either vertically or horizontally.

Below is the sample code:

```
  <div dojoType="dijit.layout.TabContainer" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" tabStrip="true">
            <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="My first tab" selected="true">
                   11
            </div>
            <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="My second tab">
                 2222
            </div>
            <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="My last tab">
               333333
            </div>
    </div>

    <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/TabContainer" style="width: 400px; height: 100px;" tabPosition="left-h" tabStrip="true">
          <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" title="My first left tab" selected="true">
           left1111
          </div>
          <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" title="My second left tab">
            left2222
          </div>
          <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" title="My last left tab">
            left3333
          </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to display these tabs below each other? The problem is that layout widgets in Dojo need to know what space they can take. They will look at their parent element to decide what size they can take.

Your first `TabContainer` has a `height` of `100%`, this seems to work fine, but it actually doesn't. The `height: 100%` makes it 0 high, the result is that any content below that container, will start to overlap.

So, in your case, your second `TabContainer` will overlap the first one.

The solution is to give it a fixed height, for example:

```html
<div dojoType="dijit.layout.TabContainer" tabStrip="true"
  style="width: 100%;height: 100px">
</div>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5yn2hLv9/

Comment: I want to display horizontal and vertical tabs in the same box.i.e.,left side of horizontal tabs i want to display vertical tabs. @Dimitri M.

Comment: @user4199704 then you will have to put the second `TabContainer` inside the first one, for example: http://jsfiddle.net/p3nqx10v/

Comment: Thanks all for the suggestion, my requirement is different. If i get the solution i will post the answer.

Comment: @user4199704 then explain your requirement. I'm pretty sure your requirement doesn't match the use cases of a `TabContainer`, but I can only know if you tell us.